# WSO2 API Manager (4.2.0) - How to build the latest version using the source?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to build the latest version of WSO2 API Manager wso2am-4.2.0 and the following error appears when I run the mvn clean install command in the <PRODUCT_HOME>\modules\distribution\product directory.

```
The project org.wso2.am:wso2am:4.2.0 (D:\APIM 4.2.0\product-apim-4.2.0\modules\distribution\product\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.wso2.am:am-parent:4.2.0: Could not transfer artifact org.wso2:wso2:pom:1.3 from/to wso2-nexus (https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.wso2.am:am-parent:4.2.0, D:\APIM 4.2.0\product-apim-4.2.0\pom.xml, line 31, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

[image]

I downloaded and set the path for Maven, set MAVEN_OPTS variable as per the documentation.
https://wso2.github.io/using-maven.html

1. How can I resolve this issue?
2. Is there a more detailed descriptive documentation on building the product?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `mvn clean install` command from the parent directory. In your case, it would be `D:\APIM 4.2.0\product-apim-4.2.0`.

You can skip the tests with the following command which will build the binary and source distributions.

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Once the build is completed the zip file can be found at `modules/distribution/product/target`

For more information refer,

https://wso2.github.io/using-maven.html

https://www.yenlo.com/blogs/building-wso2-api-manager-from-scratch/